# Is there a default value for the media attribute?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For example is

```
<style media="screen">
```

equivalent to

```
<style>
```

Also,

If not, is there a difference between the 2.

Where can I find better documentation than ...

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp

Comment: If you printed the page the first styles would not be applied, the second would.

Comment: Of course, the standard itself is better documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types and https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html#attr-style-media

Answer (score 0):

The default value is "all" -> for all devices.

So, in your example the first would only apply to screens, the second to all devices.

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html#attr-style-media):

> The default, if the `media` attribute is omitted, is "all", meaning that by default styles apply to all media.

The value of the `media` attribute is any valid [media query](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/).